# Azure in China Notification Hub Push with Baidu- Can't find method registerBaidu(String, String)

Tags: android, azure, push-notification

I want to use Azure to push notification in China. And I read the Document that it seems only can use Baidu's Platform if you want to push to Android device.

I follow the official tutorial but there is a missing method in it.

Error:(48, 24) error: cannot find symbol method registerBaidu(String,String)

here is my code:
    `private void registerWithNotificationHubs() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    hub.registerBaidu(mUserId, mChannelId);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Registered with Notification Hub - '"
                            + ConfigurationSettings.NotificationHubName + "'"
                            + " with UserId - '"
                            + mUserId + "' and Channel Id - '"
                            + mChannelId + "'");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }`
And the hub belongs to NotificationHub.

And here is my import:

```
package com.example.henryhkpush;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import com.baidu.frontia.api.FrontiaPushMessageReceiver;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.NotificationHub;
```

And i go to the NotificationHub.jar folder,there isn't exist this method“registerBaidu(String, String)”.

Did i miss something or It just can't work recently?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the NotificationHub.jar.
Normally the file you download from the official websites is NotificationHub-0.3.jar. But the method: registerBaidu() is in the NotificationHub-0.4.jar.

So you have to upgrade the library.